# mongodb aggregation very slow when $match key not in index (does tablescan?)

Tags: performance, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.collection.aggregate(

{  "$match" : {
        "key" : "mykey"

    }
}, 
{
    "$sort" : {
        "time" : -1
    }
},
{
    "$limit" : 1 
}
```

)

example document:

```
{
   key: "key1",
   time: ISODate("2014-07-04T20:04:46.904Z")
}
```

indexes

```
"time" : -1
"key" : 1,
"_id" : 1
```

when "mykey" exists in the collection the query takes 30ms, when "mykey" does not exist it takes 10s,
explain tells me indexes are used.
This is a capped collection, therefor it usually occurs that "keys" are missing.
Why does it take that long.
btw. Mongodb 2.4

further exploration:

removing the index for the sort reduces the lookup time:

explain for aggregate with and without index on the sort field shows that with index the sort gets executed at the start of the pipeline, without index on sort it gets executed as last step of the pipeline

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: why does it take that long when the key is missing.

Comment: what do you mean by "exist"? that the value exists for that key or that the field exists in the schema?

Comment: when a value for "key" doesn't exist. I'm scanning for ObjectIds in a large (>20M docs) log collection if that helps.

Comment: it would be somewhat easier to work thru this if you would share the schema along with any indexes created and a sample document.

Comment: you are using the wrong index.  the order of fields should be key:1, time:1 (as first two fields) for this query to be able to use it effectively.   As it is, you are scanning all time values in Index so that when you first the first matching key you'll be able to return.  When key doesn't exist you end up going through the entire index.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equality on `key` and sort on `time` which means that you are using the wrong index for this (your index is on `time:1, key:1` in essence).

The order of fields for the query you are running should be `key:1, time:1` (as first two fields) in order to have effective help from it.  With that index, the matched `key` value can be jumped to directly, and then if there are multiple `time` values for that `key` then they are sorted and the highest one can be immediately fetched.  If `key` is not found in the index then you're done.

As it is, the query is forced to scan all time values in Index (leading field) so that when you find the first matching key you'll be able to return. When key you are looking for doesn't exist, the query ends up scanning through the entire index before it can return.

Comment: So basically i need to use 1 multikey index, that has all match and sort parameters in the correct order.
I was using seperate indexes for these fields.
But multikey ideed did the trick

Comment: "multikey" index is an index on an array. you want to use a "compound" index - which is what you are already using, you just have it in the wrong order.